# How to send correct request to javascript page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape information from the Uber Eats website, however the html that I get with BeautifulSoup or Selenium doesn't show the html code for the restaurants I'm trying to scrape. Do I have to send a specific request to the page or something else? My code is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

myProxy = {
            "http"  : "http://10.120.118.49:8080",
            "https"  : "https://10.120.118.49:8080"
            }

headers = {'Accept': 'text/html'}

uber_city=[]
food_restaurant=[]
cities2=[]

url='https://www.ubereats.com/en-US/feed?pl=JTdCJTIyYWRkcmVzcyUyMiUzQSUyMkxvbmRvbiUyMEV5ZSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZSUyMiUzQSUyMkNoSUpjMm5TQUxrRWRrZ1JrdW9KSkJmemtVSSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZVR5cGUlMjIlM0ElMjJnb29nbGVfcGxhY2VzJTIyJTJDJTIybGF0aXR1ZGUlMjIlM0E1MS41MDMxMDE1JTJDJTIybG9uZ2l0dWRlJTIyJTNBLTAuMTE3NDcyNzk5OTk5OTk5OTklN0Q%3D'

page1 = requests.get(url, proxies=myProxy, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page1.text, 'lxml')
page1.close()

print(soup)
```

And the html code doesn't include the the html for the restaurants as in the code of the webpage below:

```
<div class="ao ew aq">
    <div class="ao bl d2 ex e2">
        <div class="ey b9 ba bb bc bd be ez"> Bodean's BBQ (Soho)
        </div>
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: the page is tsking time in page load because data comes from JS. so, you should use selenium for javascript embedded sites.

Comment: Yeah, but when I use selenium the same happens. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: @DDN1414 check below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `selenium` for such a task, as it's will slow down your process at all. the page is rendered via `JavaScript` once it's loads, Therefore, i were able to track the `XHR` request to the `JS` `API` and called it to extract the data.

> `XHR` request can be tracked within `Developer-Tools` in your browser, with `Navigating` to `Network-Tab` and check `XHR` requests made.

Check Below:

```py
import requests
import json


data = {"cacheKey": "JTdCJTIyYWRkcmVzcyUyMiUzQSUyMkxvbmRvbiUyMEV5ZSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZSUyMiUzQSUyMkNoSUpjMm5TQUxrRWRrZ1JrdW9KSkJmemtVSSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZVR5cGUlMjIlM0ElMjJnb29nbGVfcGxhY2VzJTIyJTJDJTIybGF0aXR1ZGUlMjIlM0E1MS41MDMxMDE1JTJDJTIybG9uZ2l0dWRlJTIyJTNBLTAuMTE3NDcyNzk5OTk5OTk5OTklN0Q=/DELIVERY///0/0//JTVCJTVE/",
        "feedSessionCount": {"announcementCount": 0, "announcementLabel": ""}, "userQuery": "", "date": "", "startTime": 0, "endTime": 0, "carouselId": "", "sortAndFilters": []}


headers = {
    "x-csrf-token": "x",
    'cookie': "uev2.id.xp=84c25cae-9049-4ed7-8119-b00e21bd099b; dId=f14e51e4-f3af-4da8-9cbd-f0f0024fa575; uev2.id.session=3c486ded-ffc4-4dfc-9a4e-849fa25afee4; uev2.ts.session=1583939016969; jwt-session=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1ODM5MzkwMTcsImV4cCI6MTU4NDAyNTQxN30.7-3tQOFimBd2up8wv94GsJacTnk4x1Cm498ZITSy71w; uev2.loc=%7B%22address%22%3A%7B%22address1%22%3A%22London%20Eye%22%2C%22address2%22%3A%22The%20Queen's%20Walk%2C%20South%20Bank%2C%20London%22%2C%22aptOrSuite%22%3A%22%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22%22%2C%22country%22%3A%22%22%2C%22eaterFormattedAddress%22%3A%22The%20Queen's%20Walk%2C%20South%20Bank%2C%20London%20SE1%207PB%2C%20UK%22%2C%22postalCode%22%3A%22%22%2C%22region%22%3A%22%22%2C%22subtitle%22%3A%22The%20Queen's%20Walk%2C%20South%20Bank%2C%20London%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22London%20Eye%22%2C%22uuid%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22latitude%22%3A51.503095699999996%2C%22longitude%22%3A-0.11750189999999999%2C%22reference%22%3A%22ChIJc2nSALkEdkgRkuoJJBfzkUI%22%2C%22referenceType%22%3A%22google_places%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22google_places%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22rev_geo_reference%22%7D; marketing_vistor_id=1cdd05e4-e3ea-40e3-a2d9-b8c790ba7b70; utag_main=v_id:0170ca1f682600a0ff2795e620200104e014200d00978$_sn:1$_se:6$_ss:0$_st:1583940871143$ses_id:1583939020843%3Bexp-session$_pn:3%3Bexp-session; _userUuid=; _gcl_au=1.1.1208413337.1583939021; QSI_HistorySession=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubereats.com%2Fen-US%2Ffeed%2F%3Fpl%3DJTdCJTIyYWRkcmVzcyUyMiUzQSUyMkxvbmRvbiUyMEV5ZSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZSUyMiUzQSUyMkNoSUpjMm5TQUxrRWRrZ1JrdW9KSkJmemtVSSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZVR5cGUlMjIlM0ElMjJnb29nbGVfcGxhY2VzJTIyJTJDJTIybGF0aXR1ZGUlMjIlM0E1MS41MDMxMDE1JTJDJTIybG9uZ2l0dWRlJTIyJTNBLTAuMTE3NDcyNzk5OTk5OTk5OTklN0Q%253D~1583939021598%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubereats.com%2Fen-US%2Ffeed%2F%3Fpl%3DJTdCJTIyYWRkcmVzcyUyMiUzQSUyMkxvbmRvbiUyMEV5ZSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZSUyMiUzQSUyMkNoSUpjMm5TQUxrRWRrZ1JrdW9KSkJmemtVSSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZVR5cGUlMjIlM0ElMjJnb29nbGVfcGxhY2VzJTIyJTJDJTIybGF0aXR1ZGUlMjIlM0E1MS41MDMxMDE1JTJDJTIybG9uZ2l0dWRlJTIyJTNBLTAuMTE3NDcyNzk5OTk5OTk5OTklN0Q%3D~1583939068750; _ga=GA1.2.455546941.1583939022; _gid=GA1.2.1252191334.1583939022; _fbp=fb.1.1583939022805.1654600085; _scid=0c232be0-9f0e-4e0e-a335-f92c9fa7f1f0; _sctr=1|1583877600000"
}

r = requests.post(
    "https://www.ubereats.com/api/getFeedV1?localeCode=en-US", json=data, headers=headers).json()


circ = json.dumps(r, indent=4)

print(circ)
print(r.keys())
```

Output for `r.keys()`

```
dict_keys(['status', 'data'])
```

[circ-output](https://paste.centos.org/view/raw/529086cc)

Comment: This is really cool, can you tell me how did you find the XHR request? Thank you so much!

Comment: @DDN1414 you are welcome, I've edited my answer to explain the `XHR` request. feel free to accept the answer by ticking the check mark beside the answer, up-vote if you liked as well.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, already did it! However, I didn't quite get how you reached the correct XHR requests. Do you know of some tutorial or something that demonstrates how to reach it? Also, does the `circ` output have all the restaurants in London? Thank you very much and once again sorry for the delay

Comment: @DDN1414 I've explained for you how to get the `XHR` request if you did read my answer. and yes it's have all resturant

Comment: I've learned it now, but I have one final question, how can I get the names of the restaurants into a list? I've been searching everywhere for it but I can't do it. If you could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait until page is filled with data:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "/chromedriver")
link = 'https://www.ubereats.com/en-US/feed?pl=JTdCJTIyYWRkcmVzcyUyMiUzQSUyMkxvbmRvbiUyMEV5ZSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZSUyMiUzQSUyMkNoSUpjMm5TQUxrRWRrZ1JrdW9KSkJmemtVSSUyMiUyQyUyMnJlZmVyZW5jZVR5cGUlMjIlM0ElMjJnb29nbGVfcGxhY2VzJTIyJTJDJTIybGF0aXR1ZGUlMjIlM0E1MS41MDMxMDE1JTJDJTIybG9uZ2l0dWRlJTIyJTNBLTAuMTE3NDcyNzk5OTk5OTk5OTklN0Q%3D'
browser.get(link)
time.sleep(5)

offers = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('at.ay.ej.eh')
for item in offers:
    print(item.text)
```

**Output:**

```
McDonald's® (Waterloo Station)
£ • Burgers • Breakfast and Brunch
15–25 Min
Rated 4.0 out of 5 stars based on more than 500 reviews.
4.0
(500+)
Delivery fee is £3.50.
£3.50 Delivery Fee
KFC - London - Waterloo
£ • American • Fast Food • Chicken
15–25 Min
Rated 3.9 out of 5 stars based on 221 reviews.
3.9
(221)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this does solve the problem of getting the html code for the restaurants, but a new one has been raised. Every time I run the code the class of the restaurants changes, and it never matches the one that is on the google inspect page. How can I control this?